# SP2013 calendars are starting with Tuesday even after changing the Regional Settings

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, regional-settings

We have several calendars on our site, and a few days ago they started showing Tuesday as the first day of the week instead of Monday. Nothing changed as far as I can tell, but it's possible an update got installed automatically over the weekend.

I double-checked the regional settings for the subsite AND root site (they're both having the issue), but that appears to be set correctly:

[image: Regional settings set correctly]

On the actual calendars, though, the days are ordered like this:

Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday

Has anyone run into this issue before? We dont use personal profile sites. so i can't change it on my personal settings.

Answer (score 1):

In the Regional settings, make sure the Locale is set correctly and the Time Zone matches user’s computer.

If the issue exists, try to start->Run ->IISRest and check again.

Comment: I tried doing IISRest and didn't resolve the issue. Zones are the same (SharePoint and local computers)